# Compiling Simulink Files Called by Functions

Tags: matlab, simulink, matlab-compiler

Right now I am trying to use MATLAB Compiler SDK to compile a large project. This project includes Simulink files and Matlab files. I understand that I need to compile the Simulink files before using them with the compiled MATLAB files, but the issue is that these files can not be run without the MATLAB files, and so they give me errors when I try to build them with Simulink Coder.

How can I compile the dependent Simulink code, or modify them so that they can be compiled? The code is quite complicated, and I did not write it.

Comment: What are the errors? Does Simulink model call into those MATLAB files?

Comment: The error is an undefined parameter. The Simulink model does not call the MATLAB files, but the MATLAB calls the Simulink. The Simulink model does have S-Functions, but I think I've dealt with those.